# Long crack in I joist flange

Tags: repair, flooring, joists, structural

Found a nasty crack in one of our I joists and need advice. Should I get a structural engineer over here asap or try to repair it? It’s over a foot long. Our shop was built in 2020, so I’m surprised to see this level of damage already.

[image: Wooden joist with longitudinal crack]

Comment: Have a look at the side of the flange. Do you see layers -- does the side of the flange look like the cut edge/cross section of a sheet of plywood? (that type of construction is common.) If so, does the crack run deeper than just one ply?

Answer (score 22):

That looks like typical checking just from the wood aging and drying out.  It's down the long axis of the beam vs. across the beam which would indicate a problem.

Also that portion of the beam is under tension and those splits are not going to affect the wood's strength under tension significantly.

Bottom line is that this is entirely normal and typical and the beams are generally designed with this in mind.